# JQuery Vector Map: Tooltip remains displayed on the map after click

Tags: jvectormap

I am using [JQuery VectorMap](http://jqvmap.com/).

When I click on a country, the tooltip containing the description is shown.

However, when I click on another country, the previously displayed tooltip is not removed from the screen.

I don't understand why the tooltip of the clicked region stays displayed, since the onRegionClick event does not save the state of the tooltip.

Here is the code:

```
onRegionClick: function(event, code){
if (gdpData[code]) {

$('#currencyHidden').val(wm2idCurrencyMap[code]);
$('#calculatorCurrencyToHidden').val(wm2idCurrencyMap[code]);
$('#calculatorWmCurrencyToHidden').val(wm2idCurrencyMap[code]);

submitCurrenciesFormWithOptions();
}
},

function submitCurrenciesFormWithOptions() {
// sets the form options and submits the form
$('#currenciesForm').ajaxSubmit(currenciesFormOptions);
//submitCalculatorFormWithOptions();
return false;
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: Maybe you could modify this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3xZ28/146/ to have something live to work on. jqvMaps is a fork of jVectorMap but essentially they work the same.

Answer (score 0):

Checked your onLabelShow function.

```
onLabelShow: function(e, el, code){
    el.html(el.html()+' (GDP - '+gdpData[code]+')');
};
```

jvectormap example site url. http://jvectormap.com/examples/world-gdp/